# Using datepicker within haml

Tags: javascript, haml

I am sorta new to using datepicker within haml and was hoping to get some guidance. I have included a javascript with a datepicker within my main.html along with two date fields.  Unfortunately, when I try to test the following code I get nothing.  Any idea what I might be overlooking? Any help will be greatly appricated.

```
#content

%h3
  Please enter the following information:
=form('/search', :post)
=input(:id, :report_id, class: "formbox")
=input(:date, :start_date, class: "formbox")
=input(:date, :end_date, class: "formbox")
=submit('Submit', class: "button")

:javascript
  $(function() {
    $( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  });
```

Comment: With haml, indentation is key... The way that your form is indented in your question, is that the way it's indented in your actual form?

Comment: It's currently indented the same as the question.  So I just need to move my javascript portion over?

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: nope, still can't get it to work. Will post a update once i can get it to work. I'm sure it's probably something small but I cannot pinpoint it.

Comment: Can you post any errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HAML, the way you indent is key to your code working correctly. You need to change your indentation as follows:

```
%h3
  Please enter the following information:
= form('/search', :post)
  = input(:id, :report_id, class: "formbox")
  = input(:date, :start_date, class: "formbox")
  = input(:date, :end_date, class: "formbox")
  = submit('Submit', class: "button")

:javascript
  $(function() {
    $( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  });
```