# Adding javascript to HAML markup error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to add a datepicker to my HAML markup. I started with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259780/using-datepicker-within-haml) question and tried 2 approaches to add an script:

```
%h3
  Please enter the following information:
= form('/some_path', :post)
  = input(:date, :start_date, class: "formbox")
  = input(:date, :end_date, class: "formbox")
  = submit('Submit', class: "button")

%script(type="text/javascript")
  $(function() {$( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});});
```

and

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
  });
```

**This one was finally correct, problem was in form part.**

Both produce an error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input` on line `:javascript` or `%script(type="text/javascript")`

How to fix that and add the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%script` tag expects curly brackets; in the latter example there is `=content_for` tag needed:

```
%script{data:{'foo'=> 'bar'}, 'type'=> "text/javascript"}
= content_for :javascripts do
  :javascript
    $(function() {
      $( "#start_date, #end_date" ).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
    });
```

Comment: Tried your answer - got the same syntax error on  `$(function() {` line.

Comment: Thanks for attention, the problem was in form section, replaced with helper tags and got it working. Also, `:javascript` keyword worked just as is, no `=content_for` was needed.